# systemd resource control - IOWriteIOPSMax not working?

Tags: systemd, cgroups

I'm trying to limit IO for a specific unit, but the IOWriteIOPSMax attribute does not appear to make a difference.

I initially tried IOWeight, but that is more challenging to test, the docs on IOPSMax suggest this is a pure limit.

pops os, systemd 249, cgroupv2

Running as default

```
user@x1:~/tmp$ systemd-run --user --same-dir --pipe --wait \
dd status=progress if=/dev/zero of=loadfile bs=1k count=5000024 

Running as unit: run-u233.service
4876370944 bytes (4.9 GB, 4.5 GiB) copied, 32 s, 152 MB/s 
5000024+0 records in
5000024+0 records out
5120024576 bytes (5.1 GB, 4.8 GiB) copied, 32.914 s, 156 MB/s
Finished with result: success
Main processes terminated with: code=exited/status=0
Service runtime: 33.592s
CPU time consumed: 16.924s
```

Running with limits - set deliberately very low:

```
user@x1:~/tmp$ systemd-run --user --same-dir --pipe --wait \
-p IOAccounting=yes \
-p IOWriteIOPSMax="/dev/nvme0n1 5" \
-p IOReadIOPSMax="/dev/nvme0n1 5" \
dd status=progress if=/dev/zero of=loadfile bs=1k count=5000024 

Running as unit: run-u234.service
5090277376 bytes (5.1 GB, 4.7 GiB) copied, 19 s, 268 MB/s
5000024+0 records in
5000024+0 records out
5120024576 bytes (5.1 GB, 4.8 GiB) copied, 19.2141 s, 266 MB/s
Finished with result: success
Main processes terminated with: code=exited/status=0
Service runtime: 19.899s
CPU time consumed: 16.838s
```

Both runs appear to take the same amount of time. `systemctl show unit | grep IO` confirms both attributes are set.

Watching `iostat -xd 1/ dev/nvme0n1` in another window shows 300w/s , I expected that the properties applied would reduce this to < 10, what is wrong with my approach?

Edit:
Adding `/proc/self/cgroup` info:

```
user@x1:~$ systemd-run --user --same-dir --pipe --wait -p IOAccounting=yes -p IOWriteIOPSMax="/dev/nvme0n1 5" -p IOReadIOPSMax="/dev/nvme0n1 5" cat /proc/self/cgroup
Running as unit: run-u282.service
0::/user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/app.slice/run-u282.service
```

Edit:
Running as root

```
root@x1:~# systemd-run  --same-dir --pipe --wait \
-p IOAccounting=yes \
-p IOWriteIOPSMax="/dev/nvme0n1 5" \
-p IOReadIOPSMax="/dev/nvme0n1 5" \
dd status=progress if=/dev/zero of=loadfile bs=1k count=5000024 

Running as unit: run-u1099.service
4847981568 bytes (4.8 GB, 4.5 GiB) copied, 17 s, 285 MB/s
5000024+0 records in
5000024+0 records out
5120024576 bytes (5.1 GB, 4.8 GiB) copied, 17.9437 s, 285 MB/s
Finished with result: success
Main processes terminated with: code=exited/status=0
Service runtime: 17.945s
CPU time consumed: 16.748s
IO bytes read: 0B
IO bytes written: 0B
```

Edit:
And as a standard unit. run as root

```
root@x1:/etc/systemd/system# systemctl cat testme.service
# /etc/systemd/system/testme.service
[Service]
IOAccounting=yes
IOReadIOPSMax=/root 10
IOWriteIOPSMax=/root 10
ExecStart=dd status=progress if=/dev/zero of=/root/loadfile bs=1k count=5000024 


root@x1:/etc/systemd/system# journalctl -u testme.service -f
Nov 05 14:20:25 x1 systemd[1]: Started testme.service.
Nov 05 14:20:50 x1 dd[56684]: [1.3K blob data]
Nov 05 14:20:50 x1 dd[56684]: 5000024+0 records in
Nov 05 14:20:50 x1 dd[56684]: 5000024+0 records out
Nov 05 14:20:50 x1 dd[56684]: 5120024576 bytes (5.1 GB, 4.8 GiB) copied, 24.6735 s, 208 MB/s
Nov 05 14:20:50 x1 systemd[1]: testme.service: Deactivated successfully.
Nov 05 14:20:50 x1 systemd[1]: testme.service: Consumed 17.352s CPU time.
```

(same results replacing `/root` with `/dev/nvme..` )

Comment: Try running the following command instead of `dd`: `cat /proc/self/cgroup`. Check if your process is indeed running under its own io cgroup. [edit] your question and add what you see.

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to enable `IOAccounting=yes` for `user` sessions. Try to run the same test as `root` and without `--user`, just to test my assumption.

Comment: Last request before I submit an answer: 1. Run the next commands as root, and without `--user`. 2. Add `oflag=sync` argument to your `dd` command. 3. Check if there's a difference in the transfer rate of the command with and without the `IOWriteIOPSMax` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two parts to the answer:

- When setting `IOWriteIOPSMax`, the limit is enforced through the `io.max` cgroups file. When running with `--user` mode, you cannot change your cgroups, thus it option would have no effect.
- When running `dd` the way you run, the default is to use asynchronous I/O, which means the process doesn't not block until the data is actually written to the disk. That's why `IOWriteIOPSMax` would not affect the run. In order to really test it, you'll need to use synchronous I/O so the data would actually be written to the disk. You can do that by adding the `oflag=sync` flag to your `dd` command.

#### Testing script

In order to test and confirm those conditions, I created a script that does few things:

1. Check if the `io.max` cgroup file exist, and if it actually has any limitation.
2. Run two `dd` command; One with asynchronous I/O, and the second one with synchronous I/O.

```
cat systemd_io.sh
#!/bin/bash
CGROUPS="$(</proc/self/cgroup)"
echo "/proc/self/cgroup: '$CGROUPS'" 
IO_MAX_FILE="/sys/fs/cgroup/${CGROUPS#0::/}/io.max"
if [ -f "$IO_MAX_FILE" ]
then
        IO_MAX="$(<$IO_MAX_FILE)" 
        if [ -z "$IO_MAX" ]
        then echo "$IO_MAX_FILE exists but is empty."
        else printf "Content of %s:\n%s\n" "$IO_MAX_FILE" "$IO_MAX"
        fi
else
        echo $IO_MAX_FILE does not exist.
fi
echo
echo Writing file without sync:
dd if=/dev/zero of=loadfile bs=1k count=10 2>&1 |tail -1
rm -f loadfile
echo
echo Writing file WITH oflag=sync:
dd if=/dev/zero of=loadfile bs=1k count=10 oflag=sync 2>&1 |tail -1
rm -f loadfile
echo
```

#### Running `systemd-run` with `--user` flag

- The `io.max` cgroup file isn't even created, so there's no limit to the IO.

```
root:~/tmp$ systemd-run --user --same-dir --pipe --wait -p IOWriteIOPSMax="/dev/vda 5" ./systemd_io.sh 2>/dev/null
/proc/self/cgroup: '0::/user.slice/user-0.slice/user@0.service/app.slice/run-u18.service'
/sys/fs/cgroup/user.slice/user-0.slice/user@0.service/app.slice/run-u18.service/io.max does not exist.

Writing file without sync:
10240 bytes (10 kB, 10 KiB) copied, 0.000142996 s, 71.6 MB/s

Writing file WITH oflag=sync:
10240 bytes (10 kB, 10 KiB) copied, 0.00483422 s, 2.1 MB/s
```

#### Running `systemd-run` without `--user` flag and without `IOWriteIOPSMax`

- The `io.max` cgroup file is created but empty, thus there are no limitations.
- The write ratio is for synchronous I/O is the same as for the user.

```
root:~/tmp$ systemd-run --same-dir --pipe --wait  ./systemd_io.sh 2>/dev/null
/proc/self/cgroup: '0::/system.slice/run-u187.service'
/sys/fs/cgroup/system.slice/run-u187.service/io.max exists but is empty.

Writing file without sync:
10240 bytes (10 kB, 10 KiB) copied, 0.000144849 s, 70.7 MB/s

Writing file WITH oflag=sync:
10240 bytes (10 kB, 10 KiB) copied, 0.00446492 s, 2.3 MB/s
```

#### Running `systemd-run` without `--user` flag and WITH `IOWriteIOPSMax`

- The `io.max` cgroup file has the limit defined by `IOWriteIOPSMax`.
- The asynchronous I/O is not affected (due to the reasons I mentioned above), but this time synchronous I/O is much slower than before (1.8 kB/s instead of ~2 MB/s), confirming that `IOWriteIOPSMax` works.

```
root:~/tmp$ systemd-run --same-dir --pipe --wait -p IOWriteIOPSMax="/dev/sda 5" ./systemd_io.sh 2>/dev/null
/proc/self/cgroup: '0::/system.slice/run-u189.service'
Content of /sys/fs/cgroup/system.slice/run-u189.service/io.max:
253:0 rbps=max wbps=max riops=max wiops=5

Writing file without sync:
10240 bytes (10 kB, 10 KiB) copied, 0.000136314 s, 75.1 MB/s

Writing file WITH oflag=sync:
10240 bytes (10 kB, 10 KiB) copied, 5.78732 s, 1.8 kB/s
```

Comment: thank you for the *excellent* explanation!